# Nginx - if $request_uri exists proxy_pass one url, otherwise another url

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, request-uri

I want to handle 2 cases: `test.example.com` and `test.example.com/ABC`.

1. If the entered url is the base domain (`test.example.com`), I want to `proxy_pass` a given endpoint (Let's say `example.com/home`).
2. If `test.example.com/ABC` is given, I want to `proxy_pass` to `example.com/confirm/ABC`

- test.example.com = https://example.com/home
- test.example.com/ABC = https://example.com/confirm/ABC

I made the (1) work like so:

```
server {
     listen 443 ssl;
     listen [::]:443 ssl;

     server_name test.example.com;

     location / {
         proxy_pass https://example.com/home;
     }
}
```

But I couldn't figure out how to say "If $request_uri exists, proxy_pass to different endpoint". I tried:

```
location / {
    if ($request_uri) {
       proxy_pass https://example.com/confirm/$request_uri;
    }
 
    proxy_pass https://example.com/home;
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$request_uri` always exists and is never empty. The URI for the root of your domain is a single `/` (even if it's not displayed in the browser's address bar).

The `location` block which matches that URI is `location = /`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

For example:

```
location = / {
    proxy_pass https://example.com/home;
}
location / {
    proxy_pass https://example.com/confirm/;
}
```

The first `location` block only matches the root URI `/`, and the second `location` block matches any other URI. The remainder of the URI is automatically appended to `/confirm/`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details.